# Wait for AJAX before continuing through separate function

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery

Alright... at 2am, this is where I draw the line. Help... before my laptop ends up going out the window. :)

I've tried using setTimer, callbacks, and everything else I can think of (along with a few other Stackoverflow hints of course). I've stripped out everything so I'm leaving just the base code.

What I'm looking to do is call parseRow() and before it saves the record at the end, I need to grab the associated Category (via AJAX); however, it blows right past it so category is always "undefined".

```
function parseRow(row){
    var rowArray     = row.trim().split(",");
    var date         = rowArray[0];
    var checknum     = rowArray[1];
    var payee        = rowArray[2];
    var memo         = rowArray[3];
    var amount       = rowArray[4];

    //ERROR: blows right past this one and sets the category variable BEFORE ajax returns
    var category = autoSelectCategory(payee);

    saveRecord(date, checkNum, payee, memo, category, payment, deposit);
}

function autoSelectCategory(payee) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "autoselectcategory",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            string: payee
        },
        success: function (returnedData) {
            data = returnedData;
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I added @freakish's suggestion he made in response to penartur's answer since I was a moron and didn't return the data properly - that's what I get for staying up too late. The above actually does the trick now. However, I'm going to be implementing the callback.

Comment: You can also do one thing. Just pass all those parameters in autoSelectCategory and execute the saveRecord in success itself, but i guess the better way is callback function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AJAX stands for *asynchronous*. That means that in your original code, `saveRecord` will be executed **before** the client will receive the response from the server (and, depending on the `$.ajax` implementation, it might be before the client will send the request to the server).

Additionally, you seem to misunderstand how functions work in JS. `var category = autoSelectCategory(payee);` will set the category to the return value of `autoSelectCategory`; but the `autoSelectCategory` function in your code returns nothing.

From the other side, the `data` return value of your anonymous function could only be used by `$.ajax` function (and `$.ajax` likely ignores the `success` parameter return value).

Here is the code that should work:

```
function parseRow(row){
    var rowArray     = row.trim().split(",");
    var date         = rowArray[0];
    var checknum     = rowArray[1];
    var payee        = rowArray[2];
    var memo         = rowArray[3];
    var amount       = rowArray[4];

    autoSelectCategory(payee, function (category) {    
        saveRecord(date, checkNum, payee, memo, category, payment, deposit);
    });
}

function autoSelectCategory(payee, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "autoselectcategory",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            string: payee
        },
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Comment: Since he is using `async: false`, then actually `saveRecord` **will not** be executed before `$.ajax` finishes the job. He *is* returning value incorrectly though. Defining `var data;` before `$.ajax`, setting it in `success` and returning after `$.ajax` should work. Nevertheless its a **really bad** practice to use `async: false`.

Comment: @freakish I should have notice the `async: false`. Didn't even know it is possible :)

Comment: async is deprecated. Use freakish' answer.

Comment: Freakish has the better answer. async: false will block everything and prevent your page from functioning right.

Answer (score 12):

Do not use `async: false` option. It's a pure evil (blocks **all** scripts in browser and even other tabs!) and it's deprecated since jQuery 1.8. You should use callbacks as it was always meant to be.

```
function parseRow(row) {
    /* the other code */
    autoSelectCategory(payee, function() {
        saveRecord(date, checkNum, payee, memo, category, payment, deposit);
    });
}

function autoSelectCategory(payee, callback) { // <---- note the additional arg
    $.ajax({
        url: "autoselectcategory",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            string: payee
        },
        success: function(res) {
            /* the other code */
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```