# How do I compare new ajax output with previous using divs?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I decided to build a high/low game in javascript and am running into an issue where the numbers displayed are ahead of what the variables have stored or the exact opposite. I can't seem to get them to match.

**EDIT:** I figured it out, the code ran before ajax was done causing an offset.
It helps me more when I find answers with the old code to compare with the new so I'll leave the broken code. Updated with working code at the end.

Page that helped me figure out a fix:
[Wait for AJAX before continuing through separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289884/wait-for-ajax-before-continuing-through-separate-function/11289940)

Original JavaScript:

```
var y = "0";
var z = "0";
var output_div = document.getElementById("outcome");
var last_ = document.getElementById("val");
var cardVal;

function higher(x) {

  var new_ = last_.innerHTML; //getting new value
  y = last_.getAttribute("data-old"); //getting old value

  console.log("data_old " + y);

  z = ajx(); //calling function return the value from which need to compare
  console.log("data_new " + z);
  if (x === 1) {
    if (z > y) {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Winner!";
    } else {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Loser!";
    }
  } else {
    if (z < y) {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Winner!";
    } else {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Loser!";
    }
  }
  last_.setAttribute("data-old", new_); //setting old value with current value of div

}


function ajx() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./getfacecard.php",
    success: function(response) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(response);
      var img = result[0];
      cardVal = result[1];
      document.getElementById(\'card\').src = img;
      document.getElementById(\'val\').innerHTML = cardVal;
    }

  });
  return cardVal; // return current card value in calling function

}
```

Updated Working JavaScript:

```
var lastVal = document.getElementById("lastVal"); //Last played cars value
var wl = document.getElementById("outcome"); //Shows win or lose
var newVal = document.getElementById("currentVal"); //Current face up card
var iSrc = document.getElementById("card"); //Card img
var lVal; //Last cards value from post
var iLink; //Image link from post
var nVal; //Gets new html to be sent to post.

function start(x){
//  console.log("Start:");

    ajx(function(){ //Runs ajax before continuing 
        iSrc.src = iLink; //Set new card image src
        newVal.innerHTML = nVal; //Sets Current card value in div
        lastVal.innerHTML = lVal; //Sets Last card value in div
//      console.log("-slgn"); //Consoles to track code launch order.
//      console.log("-Last Value: "+lVal);
//      console.log("-Current Value: "+nVal);
//      console.log("-Link: "+iLink);
//      console.log(x);
        if(x===1){ //If clicked higher
            if(nVal>lVal){ //If new card is higher than old card
                wl.innerHTML = "Winner!";
            }else{
                wl.innerHTML = "Loser!"
            }
        }
        if(x===2){
            if(nVal<lVal){ //If new card is lower than old card
                wl.innerHTML = "Winner!";
            }else{
                wl.innerHTML = "Loser!"
            }
        }
    });

}

function ajx(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {data:newVal.innerHTML}, //Post new card value to be returned as last card.
    url: "./getfacecard.php",

    success: function(response) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(response);
      iLink = result[0]; //img
      lVal = result[2]; //Last card
      nVal = result[1]; //New Card
//    console.log("ajax");
      callback(); //Go back and the code
    }

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `custom` attribute in your div to save your current value as old value and vice versa so only one div required here i.e: Your div look like below :

```
<div data-old="0" id="val">0</div>
```

And `js` code will look like below:

```
var y = "0";
var z = "0";
var output_div = document.getElementById("outcome");
var last_ = document.getElementById("val");

function higher(x) {

  var new_ = last_.innerHTML; //getting new value
  y = last_.getAttribute("data-old"); //getting old value

  console.log("data_old " + y);

  z = ajx(); //calling function return the value from which need to compare
  console.log("data_new " + z);
  if (x === 1) {
    if (z > y) {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Winner!";
    } else {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Loser!";
    }
  } else {
    if (z < y) {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Winner!";
    } else {
      output_div.innerHTML = "Loser!";
    }
  }
  last_.setAttribute("data-old", new_); //setting old value with current value of div

}


function ajx() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./getfacecard.php",
    success: function(response) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(response);
      var img = result[0];
      var cardVal = result[1];
      document.getElementById('card').src = img;
      document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = cardVal;
    }

  });
  return cardVal; // return current card value in calling function

}
```

In above `js` code what i done is after ajax call finishes execution it will `return cardVal` which will get pass in variable `z` and then we will compare it with `y` i.e : old value  and print required output.Also, i have return value from ajax called because when you do `document.getElementById(\'val\').innerHTML = cardVal;` still this value is not available with us in our function `higher` so to overcome this i have return that value to your calling function.

(This code is already tested and working as excepted )

Comment: The code above returned "Uncaught ReferenceError: cardVal is not defined" in console. I added a global var for cardVal but it still ended up with the same issue. After  adding var cardVal; outside the function I was able to get returns but clicking "Higher" 3 times resulted in the following console logs: data_old 0
(index):21 data_new undefined
(index):18 data_old 0
(index):21 data_new 6
(index):18 data_old 6
(index):21 data_new 6
(index):18 data_old 6
(index):21 data_new 2

Comment: First time when you run your function what's does the div has in it?

Comment: The div is updating normally it seems clicking it the first time shows: <div data-old="0" id="val">1</div> then the next time correctly sets old to 1 and inner to the new card. Using the browser console checking what z and y are: y "0" z undefined. Next run y is still 0 but its supposed to be as the first value was 0. It's updating one behind what it should be.

Comment: Currently , I am not on pc I will check this issue and let you know later. Till then can you show your updated code with html ? Because I have already tested this code and it was working fine.

Comment: Updated main to what I have now.

Comment: Instead of `last_.setAttribute("data-old", new_);` change it to `last_.setAttribute("data-old", y);` and see what does it gives.

Comment: Doing this leaves data-old as zero and never changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214443/discussion-between-swati-and-robertw).